# julia: pmap passing in vectors with indexes

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, pmap

I would like to use julia's `pmap` to do something like this:

```
pmap( f, v, inits[i])
```

where `f` is the function I want to call in parallel on `v` which is some array. I also want to pass some parameters to `f` (`inits`), but `inits` itself is an array, and I want ith parameter to be passed along to the correct process. Does this make sense?

I could do this by sorting of 'rolling my own' version of pmap, since it can be easily done with `remotecall_fetch`. Here is that implementation if the above was confusing:

```
    i=1
    nextidx() = (idx=i; i+=1; idx)
    @sync begin
      for k in 1:np
        if k != myid() || np == 1
          @async begin
            while true
              idx = nextidx()
              if idx > chains
                break
              end
              result[idx] = remotecall_fetch(k, mcmc_sub, m, iters, burnin, 
                                             thin, idx, ps[idx], p)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: How about a new 'v' whose elements are a composition of the old 'v' and its 'inits'?  Then use the standard 'pmap' with a modified 'f' that first extracts the elements (old 'v' element & its specific 'inits') within the new 'v'.

Comment: so like an [v, inits] kind of an array (if properly done)? That could work

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.  Works with my toy examples.

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to do the trick

Comment: @bdeonovic could you please post exactly what you did as an answer so this could be marked as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have some input `v` that you want to run `pmap` on. Each element of `v` also has an associated vector of inits which are stored in the columns of the matrix `inits`.

```
inits = reshape(randn(20), 5,4)
v = collect(1:4)
```

The key is to write your function to take in a tuple of your input and your inits

```
f = function(args::Tuple{Int64, Vector{Float64}})
  x, inits = args
  return sum(x * inits)
end
```

and then zip together your input and inits

```
args = collect(zip(v, [inits[:,j] for j in 1:4]))
pmap(f, args)
```